# Limit the number of object to 1 which can access static member using dot operator

Tags: c++, static

```
class Test{
public:
static int i;


};
int Test::i=0;
```

if I make 3 objects of Test t1, t2, t3. Is this possible to achieve that only t1 can access i using dot operator?

Comment: No it's not possible.

Comment: how would t1 differ from t2? they are both instances. maybe t1 inherits deeper?

Comment: What problem do you really intend to solve? Breaking the language rules certainly isn't a goal in itself.

Comment: Sounds like a request for how to implement a singleton.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf sounds more like  dispatcher than singleton. maybe if class would be designed to create new instances of itself, otherwise it would not be possible.. what it is called, factory?

Comment: Sounds like a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me. What do you *really* want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can't overload dot operator, so no, brief answer is that you can't do what you're asking for. You can  "hide" the field behind getter\setter and implement them so, probably making class a template with bool flag as a parameter, and do specialization.

```
// This is NOT working example
template <bool _bFlag> class Test
{
protected:
static int i;
public:
    int geti() { return I;}
};

template <> class Test<true>
{
protected:
    static int i;
public:
    int geti() { return i;}
};

template <> class Test<false>
{
protected:
    static int i;
    int  geti() { return i;}  // inaccessible from outside
};
```

Ok, here is problem.. different specialization will be different classes, they will have different static members. So we should declare base class.

```
class TestBase
{
protected:
    static int i;
};

template <bool _bFlag> class Test : public TestBase
    {

    public:
       int geti() { return i;}
};

template <> class Test<true> : public TestBase
{
public:
    int geti() { return i;}
};

template <> class Test<false>  : public TestBase
{
protected:
    int geti() { return i;}  // inaccessible from outside
};


int main()
{
 Test<true> t1;
 Test<false> t2, t3;

 //int i = t2.geti(); // error 
}
```

Does this fluff really cost the time to design this (and the hide of author, when it will be removed by reviewer of code)?

Comment: All those template tricks do not really achieve the OP's goal. `Test<true>` and `Test<false>` are simply two different classes, so that's "cheating". Of course, we still don't know the OP's **real goal** :)

Comment: @Christian Hackl well, that cheating is calling  creating of interface. only to change operator behavior in C++ is to change class. Unlike java or LUA, where class instance's behavior  can be modified during runtime. With use of polymorphism those classes can be made interchangeable, but yet it's too complex for such simple task as banning access to a field at compile time?

Comment: to get two different classes, one that has a `static i` and one that has not, I dont need templates.

Comment: @tobi303 thats' not behavior. that different set of members. OP asked about behavior change, while static member _still_ will be there (for internal use?)

Comment: OP wants the member not accesible for all but one object. How can you tell the difference if it is not accesible but there or just not there?

Comment: ah ok sorry, he said accessible via the dot operator... well I dont understand the question, so dont expect me to understand your answer :P

Comment: @tobi303  That's fine. We are even at not understanding his reasons XD

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do this. A `static` variable exists independent of objects and when it is public, everybody can access it.

```
int x = Test::i;   // <- no object of Test needed at all to access i
```

What do you really want to achieve? If you want to have a member variable that can be accessed by only a single instance, this is quite possible, but making that variable `static` is the wrong direction to go.